# "Host key verification failed" even with removed ~/.ssh/known_hosts

Tags: ssh

When I try to `ssh` to my server from a linux computer with debian, I just get

`Host key verification failed.`

The only help I found online was deleting the key from `~/.ssh/known_hosts`... well I did not only that, I deleted the whole `~/.ssh` just to be sure, and it didn't help either, I still have `Host key verification failed.` error.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

OK, answered.

When I run `ssh` with `-v` option, it showed me the actual error.

It was caused by mistakenly setting wrong access rights to `/dev/tty`, whatever that is, and ssh somehow didn't like it. `sudo chmod 666 /dev/tty` seemed to fix it.

Comment: Make it `666`. There's no point giving execution permission to that device.

Comment: OK, if you say so :)

Comment: I have similar problem (`debug1: read_passphrase: can't open /dev/tty: No such device or address`) but `chmod 666 /dev/tty` does not help. It works with my user, but after I switched to another user with `su` it fails.

Comment: @dma_k I had this problem as well. The fix was to run `su` with `-s /bin/bash`

Answer (score 5):

So the poster's problem has been resolved. But in case others come to this question by searching and their symptoms are not coming from the same cause:

Deleting `~/.ssh/known_hosts` (or just the offending line in it) will purge the cached host key. However, there is also a system-wide cache, which will be stored someplace like `/etc/ssh/ssh_known_hosts`. Host keys won't be cached there unless that's specifically requested. But if you're having host key verification issues, have a look in both of these files.

Answer (score 1):

It is also possible to run into this issue in various other ways, especially when dealing with Windows which may have several implementations of SSH tacked on to it.

I ran into this when ssh'ing into a Windows 10 machine that was running SSH server under Cygwin. When you run `ssh` from that prompt, it runs the cygwin version of ssh, which uses ~/.ssh to store the ssh files --- under cygwin that is /home/username.

However, if you run `git` from that same prompt, and Git has been installed via Windows (which in my case it had been), it uses the ssh files from C:\Users\username.ssh.

Normally you run `ssh hostname` to cache the host key for git, but in this case it does not work, since there are different known_hosts files.

Once I copied the key from one known_hosts file to the other, the `git` commands worked fine.